# Scraping (BeautifulSoup) no tags

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am very new to scraping, so as I understand, BeautifulSoup only extracts the data found inside tags (with functions like get, find, find_all ...)

The source code of the website i am scraping is displaying the various items inside the same tag

and that's what an 'item' looks like in the source code (so what bothers me is that these items are only separated by commas (,) ) :

```
{
                    "id1" : "121130815",
                    "id2" : "113840",

                }
```

How do I get this item for example ?

Thank you very much

Comment: You should use json, not bs4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing values from a JSON file using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835559/parsing-values-from-a-json-file-using-python)

Comment: Btw just to be clear, you'll still use BeautifulSoup to extract the <script> tag, and only then pass it to `json.loads`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I, and the other answer mentions, [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) is the place to get started when it comes to unstructured data.

Start with parsing your string...

```
import json

json_str = """{
                    "idannonce" : "121130815",
                    "idagence" : "113840",
                    "idtiers" : "169816",
                    "typedebien" : "Appartement",
                    "typedetransaction" : ["vente"],
                    "idtypepublicationsourcecouplage" : "SL",

                    ...

                    "si_sdEau" : "0",
                    "nb_photos" : "6",
                    "prix" : "745000",
                    "surface" : "76"
                }"""

json_data = json.loads(json_str)

print(json_data)
```

What's important is the `json.loads` function, which does all the heavy lifting, decoding your json string into an actual python object.

From this, we get a `dict` object that looks like this:

```
{'si_balcon': '1', 'affichagetype': [{'name': 'list', 'value': True}], 'codepostal': '75016', 'typedetransaction': ['vente'], 'naturebien': '1', 'etage': '1', 'position': '0', 'idtypechauffage': 'central', 'idtypecuisine': 'séparée', 'nb_photos': '6', 'prix': '745000', 'nb_pieces': '3', 'idtypecommerce': '0', 'idtypepublicationsourcecouplage': 'SL', 'si_sdEau': '0', 'codeinsee': '750116', 'cp': '75016', 'nb_chambres': '2', 'idagence': '113840', 'si_sdbain': '1', 'typedebien': 'Appartement', 'idannonce': '121130815', 'produitsvisibilite': 'AD:AC:AG:BB:AW', 'surface': '76', 'idtiers': '169816'}
```

Now, you can access all your data by iterating over it in a loop, like this:

```
for key in json_data:
    print(key, ':', json_data[key])
```

This prints out:

```
si_balcon : 1
affichagetype : [{'name': 'list', 'value': True}]
codepostal : 75016
typedetransaction : ['vente']
naturebien : 1

...

produitsvisibilite : AD:AC:AG:BB:AW
surface : 76
idtiers : 169816
```

And so on. You can access any element you want simply by doing `json_data[someKey]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not HTML, it's JSON. BeautifulSoup is a library for parsing HTML code, not simply *web pages*. Web pages can be of many different formats, depending on your definition of a page.

In this case, you're faced with a site that is returning JSON, so you need to select the correct tool. You need to use `json`, Python's built in JSON library. You can read more about the json module [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

You should also read a bit about JSON since you're unfamiliar with it. [here](https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/) is a nice introduction to the format.